# How can I gensym when writing a compiler in Kanren?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme, minikanren

I'm writing a compiler from an esolang to WebAssembly, using [CHICKEN Scheme's miniKanren](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/mini-kanren). My compiler already works somewhat, but I'd like to extend it with support for named local registers and I'm not sure how to proceed.

CHICKEN has a [gensym](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59493025/264985) with the following non-relational behavior:

```lisp
#;1> (gensym)
g18
#;2> (gensym "asdf")
asdf19
#;3> (gensym 'asdf)
asdf20
```

It would be nice if I could generate semi-readable registers in miniKanren. WebAssembly text tools usually want named registers to start with "$", as well. Given these constraints, I presumed that I could hack up a register-naming relation using `gensym`, `symbolo`, and `project`, but I'm not sure whether that is a practical solution. I also presume that I could write a custom walker against the underlying µKanren API, but that goes beyond portable miniKanren.

Is there a standard solution for this?

My compiler source [is available](https://osdn.net/users/corbin/pf/cammy/scm/blobs/master/movelist/cammy-wasm.scm), but likely the only relevant part is my current hack with `project` and `little-endian->number` for numbered registers:

```lisp
; The successor function.
; Nat <-> Nat
(define (succ° n m) (+o n (build-num 1) m))

; A prelude which loads the given number of local params onto the stack.
; Nat <-> WAT Insts
(define (prelude° plen prelude)
  (conde
    ((zeroo plen) (== prelude '()))
    ((fresh (len lude) (succ° len plen) (prelude° len lude)
            (project (len) (appendo lude `((local.get ,(little-endian->number len))) prelude))))))
```