# How can I provide an imperative default for a relation in miniKanren?

Tags: chicken-scheme, minikanren

(I am using CHICKEN Scheme's miniKanren, but I would appreciate portable answers!)

Suppose I have some relation:

```lisp
(define (rel° x)
  (conde
    ((pred?° x))
    ((== x (my-awesome-imperative-thing)))))
```

The intention is that this relation can allow `x` to be either ground or variable. When it is ground, it satisfies some relationally-computed predicate. When it's variable, it satisfies the predicate and also is unified with some imperative value-generating procedure's output.

There's a relatively obvious problem, though; `conde` clauses need to be idempotent. Suppose my imperative thing isn't idempotent, but I can guarantee that we'll only call `rel°` at most once per logic variable; if nothing else grounds that variable, then `rel°` will be the "writer" of the variable and all other relations will be the "readers", and it's safe/correct-ish. In this special case, **is this pattern possible with miniKanren?** And if you want to use more words, **what are the costs and tradeoffs?**

My motivation is to explore a possible solution for [an existing question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74828541/264985). In that case, the relation is something like:

```lisp
(define (gensym° x)
  (conde
    ((symbol° x))
    ((== x (gensym)))))
```

I've tried a few different things, but nothing works yet.